# Terminal based Norton Commander program

Tags: debian, files, terminal

I am looking for a terminal-based file manager like the good old Norton Commander or Total Commander...but all I have found so far are graphical and hence don't run in terminal.

Is there any?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A look-like of the old Norton Commander in Unix is Midnight Commander. I have been using it for years, and in some situations it is particularly useful.

In Debian to install it, do:

```
apt-get install mc
```

To run it you call

```
mc
```

Besides the familiar text graphical interface, in the bottom (command) line you can also perform shell commands.

Some functionalities are also associated to commands by default, and you can create new associations.

Midnight Commander also understands ssh/scp and one of the two text windows can be a remote one.

https://www.midnight-commander.org

Comment: Thanks for that! I was instantly transferred back to high school :)